# how to redirect a webpage ending with "/" using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website and i am using .htaccess to generate SEO friendly url. I want if someone type: mysitename.com/anypagename he should be redirected to mysitename.com/anypagename/

The basic is i want to concat a "/" at the end. Can anyone tell me the how to write this in my .htaccess file

Answer (score 2):

Try following rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NE,QSA]
```

`R=301` will redirect with https status 301
`L` will make last rule
`NE` is for no escaping query string
`QSA` will append your existing query parameters

`$1` is your REQUEST_URI

**PS:** If you want to avoid appending a `/` after a regular file then add this condition as well above:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: +1, removed my answer, as it would cause a redirect loop.  Should drink my coffee before answering in the morning ;)